# Console application questions (build release/ not loading solution file)

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2005, build, release, console-application

I've got a couple questions about .net console applications.

I created the console app, and included a solution file during the create, but when I open the solution file, it only shows the project, not the solution. Why doesn't the solution load in the solution explorer?

Also, I don't seem to be able to build the project in 'Release' mode; only debug. I switched the 'Compile/Configuration' and 'Debug/Configuration' to Release, but it doesn't build the 'bin\release' folder.

Any pointers to docs for this would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I've not used VS2005 for a while, but I don't think that the solution level is shown in the solution explorer until you have more than one project included.

Answer (score 0):

To switch to the Debug or Release configuration quickly

- On the Standard toolbar, choose either Debug or Release from the Solution Configurations list box.

From [here.](http://127.0.0.1:47873/help/0-5300/ms.help?method=page&id=57B6BBB7-F2AF-48F7-8773-127D75034ED2&product=VS&productVersion=100&topicVersion=100&locale=EN-US&topicLocale=EN-US)